# Algebra Computation Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to prove the following:

> if $ F = \frac A B D $, and $ G = \frac B{ A - C } D $, then $ G > 0 $ if and only if $ F > 1 $.

To prove the theorem I rewrite $ G $ in term of $ F $, so I got:
$$ G = \frac { B ^ 2 } { A ( A - C ) }F >0 $$
But I got nowhere. How can I write $ G $ in terms of $ F $ to prove what I mentioned above ($ G > 0 $ if and only if $ F > 1 $)?

Thank you

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please rewrite.

Comment: Please realize how important parentheses are in mathematics. If you're dividing by $A-C$ then you must put parentheses around that expression. If not, it is $\frac BA - C$.

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is false: let $A=-2$, $B=-1$, $C=-3$, and $D=1$.

Then $F=\frac{\frac{A}{B}}{D}=\frac{A}{BD}=\frac{-2}{-1\cdot1}=2>1$, but $G=\left(\frac{B}{A-C}\right)D=\frac{BD}{A-C}=\frac{-1\cdot1}{-2-(-3)}=\frac{-1}{1}=-1<0$.

See that it **must** be false, since your equation for $F$ doesn't depend on $C$ at all. Thus given $A$, $B$, and $D$ so that $F>1$, you can always conspire to find a $C$ such that $G\leq0$.

Comment: I suspect that there are constraints on $A, B, C, D$ that the OP did not provide.

Comment: Perhaps, but I cannot read minds.